# extract value from dataframe to perform t.test in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a gene expression dataframe with 500 rows and 38 column. I would like to perform t.test for the two groups (column 1-27 and column 28-39) for a specific gene **at row 435**.
Here is my R code

```
x <- df[435,1:27]
y <- df[435,28:38]
t.test(x,y)
```

output of x is

```
  G1    G2    G3    G4    G5    G6    G7    G8    G9    G10
```

435 -0.19524 -0.13841 -0.05966 -0.0742 -0.4371 0.05094 0.45927 0.04794 -0.495 0.39688

```
   G11    G12    C13    G14    G15   G16    G17    G18    G19    G20 

 -0.3524 0.04483 -0.25422 0.2458 -0.49332 -0.18619  -0.56592 -0.13109 -0.103 -0.57249
   G21    G22    G23    G24    G25    G26    G27
```

435  -0.26623 0.02744 0.07891 -0.04138 -0.35251 0.17627 0.90422

Output of y is

```
    G28     G29      G30    G31     G32     G33     G34     G35
```

435 -0.20156  -0.56749  0.1803  0.47034  0.43657  0.31767  0.29962 0.62897

G36     G37     G38

0.32455 0.22439 -0.07216

And after running t.test
a message given to me

> Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx),
>   abs(my))) stop("data are essentially constant") :    missing value
>   where TRUE/FALSE needed In addition: Warning messages: 1: In
>   mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA 2:
>   In mean.default(y) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

However, if I input the data in this way, the t.test can perform

```
x <- c(-0.19524,-0.13841,-0.05966,-0.0742,-0.4371,0.05094,0.45927,0.04794,-0.495,0.39688,-0.3524,0.04483,-0.25422,0.2458,-0.49332,-0.18619,-0.56592,-0.13109,-0.103,-0.57249,-0.26623,0.02744,0.07891,-0.04138,-0.35251,0.17627,0.90422)

y <- c(-0.20156,-0.56749,0.1803,0.47034,0.43657,0.31767,0.29962,0.62897,0.32455,0.22439,-0.07216)
```

How can I modify my R code so that the t.test can perform in RStudio?
Thanks

Comment: `x <- unlist(df[435,1:27]);
    y <- unlist(df[435,28:38]);
    t.test(x,y)` A row from a dataframe is a dataframe with one row. (A dataframe is a list.) A row from a matrix is a vector.

Comment: thank you for your reply. However unlist also give the same output of x and y as stated in the question. Error in var(x) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: Please put a [mre] in your question. ... `dput(df[435,])`

Comment: I use a new command y<- unname(unlist(df[435,28:38])) > y [1] -0.20156 -0.56749 0.1803 0.47034 0.43657 0.31767 0.29962 0.62897 0.32455 0.22439 -0.07216 **13257 Levels: -0.00174 -0.00363 -0.00552 -0.00742 -0.00932 -0.01123 -0.01314 -0.01506 -0.01697 -0.0189 -0.02082 -0.02275 -0.02469 ... V38** > class(y) [1] "factor" how can I remove the line 13257 Levels:...…….. If I remove this line, I think the t.test can perform properly

Comment: Eventually all your columns in the dataframe are factors (i.e. not numeric). Normally this refers to a problem during reading the data from an external file. At the current state you can try to work around: `x <- as.numeric(df[435, 1:27])` ...

Comment: > y<- as.numeric(unname(unlist(df[435,28:38])))
> y
 [1]    94  1470  2748  4101  5392  6679  7984  8997  9976
[10] 11213 12110
> class(y)
[1] "numeric"      but all the negative values have changed to positive value and the values are different from the original one

Comment: sorry, it has to be `as.numeric(as.character(...))`

Comment: Thank you so much. The t.test perform properly.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Comment: I recommend going back to the command to import the data. Ask yourself: "Why are my data not numeric?"

Comment: I shorten the command :  as.numeric(df[435,28:38])  , now it can convert the extracted dataframe  to numeric

Comment: That is a little bit strange. If your variable is imported as factor, then `as.numeric()` produces the indices of the levels. OK, eventually you use `stringsAsFactors =TRUE` in a R pre 4.x during read - in this case `as.numeric()` is sufficient.